# How to change the timeZone in SwiftDate?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftdate

I have displayed the list of timezones in my app. If user selects a particular timezones, I need to change the local timezone to the selected timezone by the user.

```
let region = Region(tz: timeZoneName.timeZone  , cal: cal, loc: cal.locale!)
let date = Date().inRegion(region: region).absoluteDate
```

Here is the problem, the region is changed to the selected timezone but the date issuing the local timezone.

Answer (score 2):

A `Date` contains no timezone. From apple's docs: *A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone.*

The timezone comes into play as soon as you want to present a date to the user. And that's what a `DateFormatter` is for. As @AlexWoe89 already pointed out, it let's you convert a string, containing a date into a `Date` object, but also lets you convert a given date into a string representing the date in the time zone you set to the `timeZone` property of `DateFormatter`.

```
let date = Date()

var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Los_Angeles")
let dateString1 = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Germany/Berlin")
let dateString2 = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

This will store `2017-10-23 04:27` in dateString1, while the same date leads to `2017-10-23 13:27` in dateString2.

Comment: Hi, How to convert the DateInRegion to Date  @D. Mika

Comment: By calling .absoluteDate. But I don't know very much about SwiftDate library, to be honest. But I guess DateInRegion has a way to get a String from it's containing date, without using absoluteDate and a DateFormatter.

Comment: Thank you @D. Mika

Comment: Here, I want to get the output as Date format instead of String. How should I get in Date?  @D. Mika

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormatter` as a solution, try something like this:

```
let dateString = "<yourDateAsString>"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // => there are a lot of identifiers you can use
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.defaultDate = Date()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm” // => your needed time format

let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```